# What js plugin can draw parts of body in a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, plugins

I need to draw big parts of the body(head, legs, hands etc) in browser and users will choose parts. After click on chosen part it will increase and show its little parts that clickable too( for example, for head -  eye, nose, jaw etc). What js plugin can do it? I need it for site for the medical sector. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use canvas rather than a plugin.

Here's a good tutorial.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes

OR if you want to go 'oldskool' then use CSS on divs.
https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

For something more complex like involving possibly 3d you maybe best to look at Unity, however some of these things already exist such as this
http://www.ikonet.com/en/health/virtual-human-body/virtualhumanbody.php
or
http://www.healthline.com/human-body-maps
or 
http://www.anatronica.com/systems/the-skeletal-system/

If its for educational purposes it's possible one of these will have a flexible license or be willing to share.

Comment: Thanks. I think so too, but maybe there is some libs to simplify it. Maybe they can draw 3d body models or 2d at least and do not need to search for images.

Comment: Ah I think I misread the question.  I've updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I think, simply will use svg parts from http://www.innerbody.com